# How to Launch uber eats app from a custom Android app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, uber-api

I'm trying to launch the app uber eats from another application. My application uses Cordova and angular.

I'm using the following code:

```
var url = 'https://www.ubereats.com/';
if (isPhoneGap()) {
  if (isAndroid()) {
    url = 'com.ubercab.eats:';
  } else if (isIOS()) {
    url = 'uber-eats-food-delivery://www.ubereats.com/?';
  }
}
window.open(url,'_system');
```

But this does not open the uber eat app. How can I make my app start the uber eats app?

Answer (score 2):

Your android link doesn't contain two forward slashes. If you do not include them, the browser is going to assume it's a relative link and fail to properly navigate to your URL. It should be `com.ubercab.eats://`.

I'm assuming your [deep links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/) are actually correct. As far as I know, Uber Eats does not make this information public, nor do they seem to provide any developer documentation or API. If these aren't correct, you'll likely have to derive the proper links with reverse engineering.